# How to expect that an exception is thrown in flutter method test?

Tags: flutter

this is the test I have written in flutter for unit testing-

```
test('alphanumeric check', () {
final result = dateFormateDdMmmYY('123abc');
expect(result, const FormatException('Invalid date format', '123abc'));
});
```

but it is not catching the exception and my test is failing.

the method i m testing is as below-

```
String dateFormateDdMmmYY(String date) {
final now = DateTime.parse(date);
final formatter = DateFormat(ddMMMYYFormat).format(now);
return formatter;
}
```

can anyone help?

i m trying to catch the exception which is bound to happen but it is not catching